# Creating a shortcut with Powershell not working as intended

Tags: powershell

thanks for trying to help me^^
And sorry for my bad English(maybe?)

I'm trying to create a shortcut to a PowerShell-Script to execute it.
I'm using:

```
$WshShell = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell
$link = $wshshell.CreateShortcut(”$home\Desktop\TimeStamp.lnk”)
$link.targetpath = ("%windir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noexit -File " + '"' + ($SaveDir + "\TimeStamp.ps1") + '"')
$link.save()
```

`$SaveDir` is the Path where the Script is.
It creates the shortcut, but then there is a error: `(In German sorry) Der Wert liegt außerhalb des erwarteten Bereichs.`
I tried to find a way to solve the problem. I now know whats the problem: It puts a `"` at the start and the end of the Target Location in the Properties of the Shortcut. Is there any way to prevent that?

Comment: google translation of the german listed in the Question >>> `Der Wert liegt außerhalb des erwarteten Bereichs` = `The value is outside the expected range` <<<

Comment: normally there is a great deal more detail in Powershell error messages. for instance, you usually get the line of code that triggered the error. PLEASE post the FULL error in your Question.

Comment: should `$link = $wshshell.CreateShortcut(”$home\Desktop\TimeStamp.lnk”)` be `$link = $wshshell.CreateShortcut("$env:userprofile\Desktop\TimeStamp.lnk")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a shortcut where you have arguments for the executable lik in your question, you will need to at least also use the `Arguments` property.

You can use this function which allows you to set all kinds of properties for a new shortcut, including the option to have the executable run as Administrator.

```
function New-Shortcut {
    [CmdletBinding()]  
    Param (   
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$TargetPath,                # the path to the executable
        # the rest is all optional
        [string]$ShortcutPath = (Join-Path -Path ([Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")) -ChildPath 'New Shortcut.lnk'),
        [string[]]$Arguments = $null,       # a string or string array holding the optional arguments.
        [string[]]$HotKey = $null,          # a string like "CTRL+SHIFT+F" or an array like 'CTRL','SHIFT','F'
        [string]$WorkingDirectory = $null,
        [string]$Description = $null,
        [string]$IconLocation = $null,      # a string like "notepad.exe, 0"
        [ValidateSet('Default','Maximized','Minimized')]
        [string]$WindowStyle = 'Default',
        [switch]$RunAsAdmin
    ) 
    switch ($WindowStyle) {
        'Default'   { $style = 1; break }
        'Maximized' { $style = 3; break }
        'Minimized' { $style = 7 }
    }
    $WshShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell

    # create a new shortcut
    $shortcut             = $WshShell.CreateShortcut($ShortcutPath)
    $shortcut.TargetPath  = $TargetPath
    $shortcut.WindowStyle = $style
    if ($Arguments)        { $shortcut.Arguments = $Arguments -join ' ' }
    if ($HotKey)           { $shortcut.Hotkey = ($HotKey -join '+').ToUpperInvariant() }
    if ($IconLocation)     { $shortcut.IconLocation = $IconLocation }
    if ($Description)      { $shortcut.Description = $Description }
    if ($WorkingDirectory) { $shortcut.WorkingDirectory = $WorkingDirectory }

    # save the link file
    $shortcut.Save()

    if ($RunAsAdmin) {
        # read the shortcut file we have just created as [byte[]]
        [byte[]]$bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($ShortcutPath)
        $bytes[21] = 0x22      # set byte no. 21 to ASCII value 34
        [System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($ShortcutPath, $bytes)
    }

    # clean up the COM objects
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($shortcut) | Out-Null
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($WshShell) | Out-Null
    [System.GC]::Collect()
    [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
}
```

Using your example, use it like this:

```
$SaveDir = 'D:\'     #'#  the path to the .ps1 file

$props = @{
    'ShortcutPath' = Join-Path -Path ([Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")) -ChildPath 'TimeStamp.lnk'
    'TargetPath'   = '%windir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe'
    'Arguments'    = '-NoExit -NoLogo -File "{0}"' -f (Join-Path -Path $SaveDir -ChildPath 'TimeStamp.ps1')
    # add more parameters here when needed
}

New-Shortcut @props
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it out and it worked perfect. Tahnk you very much^^